# Mix OCSP stapling + CRL in a hierarchy of CAs

Tags: ocsp, crl

In an architecture with a root CA and a daughter CA, is it possible to combine OCSP stapling and CRL check?

More precisely, is it possible for a client:

1. to connect to an https server
2. verify the validity of the server's certificate with ocsp stapling (the daughter CA issued the certificate for the https server)
3. then check for no-revocation of the certificate of the daughter CA with CRL (certificate revocation list)?

The use case is if the root CA is off (best practices) or multi stapling is impossible.
Of course, if the root CA is off, the CRL file is available elsewhere.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes this is possible in theory which does not mean that it is actually done by common clients. Most clients don't do CRL checking by default and many neither do OCSP checking also.